# How to Extract All Crypto Symbols from Coinmarketcap

Tags: python, web-scraping, symbols, cryptocurrency, coinmarketcap

I am using the following code to extract some data from Coinmarketcap by inserting the symbols of the coins one by one, but since there are new cryptos added to the list everyday, I need to extract all the cryptos at once from https://coinmarketcap.com/coins/views/all/ in order to have the updated list every day. How could I modify the following code so that I have all the crypto symbols in a text file first and then do the rest? Your help is highly appreciated.

```
import time
import requests


a = []


while True:
          try: 
             x = input("Type the symbols of The currencies. Write 'done' when you are done: ")
             open('/Users/DearUser/crypto_symbol_3.txt', 'a').close()
             if x.upper() == "DONE":
                break

             def get_timestamp(datetime: str):
                 return int(time.mktime(time.strptime(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')))


             def get_btc_quotes(start_date: str, end_date: str):
                 start = get_timestamp(start_date)
                 end = get_timestamp(end_date)
                 url = f'https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/ohlcv/historical?symbol={x}&convert=USD&time_start={start}&time_end={end}'
                 return requests.get(url).json() 



             data = get_btc_quotes(start_date='2021-11-09',
                                     end_date='2021-11-11')




             import pandas as pd
             data_flat = [quote['quote']['USD'] for quote in data['data']['quotes']]
             df = pd.DataFrame(data_flat)
             c = df.iat[1,5]
             if c==0:
                print("The marketcap of your entry is zero. Please try another one...")
             if x not in open('/Users/DearUser/crypto_symbol_3.txt', 'r').read() and c!=0:
                open('/Users/DearUser/crypto_symbol_3.txt', 'a').write(f'\"{x}\": {c},\n')
             elif x in open('/Users/DearUser/crypto_symbol_3.txt', 'r').read():
                  print("Your entry already exists! Please try again...")      
          except:
                print("Your input is not valid! Please try again...")
s = open('/Users/DearUser/crypto_symbol_3.txt', 'r').read()
print(s)
```

Comment: did you see API documentation [Listings Latest](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems API has function for this [Listings Latest](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest).
Documentation for this function even mentions page which you add in question

https://coinmarketcap.com/coins/views/all/

---

Function has `limit` 5000 symbols but if you change `start` then you can get next symbols.
This way I get `7541` symbols.

```
import requests

url = 'https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'

for start in range(1, 20000, 5000):

    params = {
        'start': start,
        'limit': 5000,
    }

    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    data = r.json()
    
    for number, item in enumerate(data['data']):
        print(f"{start+number:4} | {item['symbol']:5} | {item['date_added'][:10]}")
```

Result: (first 100 symbols with `date_added`)

```
   1 | BTC   | 2013-04-28
   2 | ETH   | 2015-08-07
   3 | BNB   | 2017-07-25
   4 | USDT  | 2015-02-25
   5 | SOL   | 2020-04-10
   6 | ADA   | 2017-10-01
   7 | XRP   | 2013-08-04
   8 | DOT   | 2020-08-19
   9 | USDC  | 2018-10-08
  10 | DOGE  | 2013-12-15
  11 | SHIB  | 2020-08-01
  12 | AVAX  | 2020-07-13
  13 | LUNA  | 2019-07-26
  14 | LTC   | 2013-04-28
  15 | WBTC  | 2019-01-30
  16 | BUSD  | 2019-09-20
  17 | CRO   | 2018-12-14
  18 | UNI   | 2020-09-17
  19 | LINK  | 2017-09-20
  20 | ALGO  | 2019-06-20
  21 | BCH   | 2017-07-23
  22 | MATIC | 2019-04-28
  23 | VET   | 2017-08-22
  24 | XLM   | 2014-08-05
  25 | AXS   | 2020-08-31
  26 | MANA  | 2017-09-17
  27 | ICP   | 2021-03-23
  28 | TRX   | 2017-09-13
  29 | FTT   | 2019-07-31
  30 | UST   | 2020-09-21
  31 | FIL   | 2017-12-13
  32 | DAI   | 2019-11-22
  33 | ETC   | 2016-07-24
  34 | EGLD  | 2020-09-04
  35 | ATOM  | 2019-03-14
  36 | THETA | 2018-01-17
  37 | BTCB  | 2019-06-18
  38 | HBAR  | 2019-09-17
  39 | NEAR  | 2020-08-11
  40 | FTM   | 2018-10-29
  41 | XTZ   | 2017-10-06
  42 | GRT   | 2020-12-17
  43 | XMR   | 2014-05-21
  44 | HNT   | 2020-06-05
  45 | EOS   | 2017-07-01
  46 | SAND  | 2020-08-05
  47 | KLAY  | 2020-03-30
  48 | FLOW  | 2021-01-27
  49 | CAKE  | 2020-09-25
  50 | AAVE  | 2020-10-02
  51 | MIOTA | 2017-06-13
  52 | XEC   | 2021-07-08
  53 | KDA   | 2020-05-31
  54 | LRC   | 2017-08-30
  55 | LEO   | 2019-05-21
  56 | KSM   | 2019-12-12
  57 | NEO   | 2016-09-08
  58 | BSV   | 2018-11-09
  59 | MKR   | 2017-01-29
  60 | QNT   | 2018-08-10
  61 | ENJ   | 2017-11-01
  62 | CHZ   | 2019-07-01
  63 | RUNE  | 2019-07-23
  64 | ONE   | 2019-06-01
  65 | STX   | 2019-10-28
  66 | WAVES | 2016-06-02
  67 | BTT   | 2019-01-31
  68 | HOT   | 2018-04-29
  69 | AMP   | 2020-09-08
  70 | ZEC   | 2016-10-29
  71 | AR    | 2020-05-27
  72 | DASH  | 2014-02-14
  73 | COMP  | 2020-06-16
  74 | KCS   | 2017-10-24
  75 | CELO  | 2020-05-22
  76 | CRV   | 2020-08-14
  77 | NEXO  | 2018-05-01
  78 | IOTX  | 2018-05-25
  79 | TFUEL | 2019-03-28
  80 | WAXP  | 2017-12-21
  81 | HT    | 2018-02-03
  82 | XEM   | 2015-04-01
  83 | BAT   | 2017-06-01
  84 | OKB   | 2019-04-30
  85 | DCR   | 2016-02-10
  86 | ICX   | 2017-10-27
  87 | QTUM  | 2017-05-24
  88 | OMG   | 2017-07-14
  89 | TUSD  | 2018-03-06
  90 | MINA  | 2021-03-02
  91 | YFI   | 2020-07-18
  92 | RVN   | 2018-03-10
  93 | VGX   | 2017-07-18
  94 | SUSHI | 2020-08-28
  95 | UMA   | 2020-05-25
  96 | AUDIO | 2020-10-20
  97 | REV   | 2017-11-01
  98 | SCRT  | 2020-05-19
  99 | ZIL   | 2018-01-25
 100 | VLX   | 2019-10-03
```