# can't retrieve data after 10 row in a 100 row table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to retrieve data from [coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/) first page.
And this is the code my code to get the data I want from table

```
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}
link = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/', headers = headers).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(link, "html.parser")
main_table = soup.body.tbody
trs = main_table.find_all('tr')

def rank(tr):
    return tr.find('p', {'class': 'sc-1eb5slv-0 etpvrL'}).text

def name(tr):
    return tr.find('p', {'class': 'sc-1eb5slv-0 iworPT'}).text

def symbol(tr):
    return tr.find('p', {'class': 'sc-1eb5slv-0 gGIpIK coin-item-symbol'}).text

def mc(tr):
    temp = tr.find('p', {'class': 'sc-1eb5slv-0 hykWbK'})
    string = temp.find('span', {'class': 'sc-1ow4cwt-1 ieFnWP'}).text
    return ''.join(string.replace('$','').split(','))

def volumn(tr):
    temp = tr.find('p', {'class': 'sc-1eb5slv-0 hykWbK font_weight_500'}).text
    return ''.join(temp.replace('$', "").split(','))

with open('{}.csv'.format(datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")), 'w') as f:
    f.write('rank, name, symbol, market cap, volumn\n')
    for i in range(len(trs)):
        f.write(rank(trs[i]))
        f.write(',')
        f.write(name(trs[i]))
        f.write(',')
        f.write(symbol(trs[i]))
        f.write(',')
        f.write(mc(trs[i]))
        f.write(',')
        f.write(volumn(trs[i]))
        f.write('\n')
```

the above code is fine just for the 10 row of each page and after tenth row it won't work.
I double check the tags and nothing change after 10 row but somehow they don't exist in soup after 10 row.
what should I do to fix this?

Comment: you have the most common problem: page uses JavaScript to add values but `requests`, `BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`. You may use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. OR you can try to use `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to get url used by JavaScript to get data. And later use this url in your code to get data. Usually JavaScript get data as JSON which can be simply converted to Python dictionary and it doesn't need `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: This page has also [API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) for programmers - and you may try get data using API.

Comment: if you use `search` at the top of page to search `coinmarketcap` then you can find many questions with the same or similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I found my previous answer for similar question.

[How to Extract All Crypto Symbols from Coinmarketcap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70027278/how-to-extract-all-crypto-symbols-from-coinmarketcap/70028568#70028568)

which uses `API`  [/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest) which doesn't need `API Key`

---

It uses the same code but it displays different data.

It gives almost 9500 rows.

```
import requests

url = 'https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'


for start in range(1, 20000, 5000):

    params = {
        'start': start,
        'limit': 5000,
    }

    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    data = r.json()
    
    for number, item in enumerate(data['data']):
         #print(f"{start+number:4} | {item['symbol']:5} | {item['date_added'][:10]} | {item['quote']['USD']['price']}")
         usd = item['quote']['USD']
         print(f"{start+number:4} | {item['name']:20} | {item['symbol']:20} | {usd['price']:25} | {usd['market_cap']:20} | {usd['volume_24h']:12}")
```

Result:

```
   1 | Bitcoin              | BTC                  |         37583.10571031953 |    712944938281.2621 | 20506963757.761803
   2 | Ethereum             | ETH                  |        2605.4265612647923 |    312019186748.4554 | 14735857986.984612
   3 | Tether               | USDT                 |        1.0004365827321502 |    79582785654.62805 | 52322182961.31001
   4 | BNB                  | BNB                  |         360.8294815571075 |   59578995228.327576 | 1506217337.3376758
   5 | USD Coin             | USDC                 |        0.9998571962594189 |    53366037535.38875 | 3906120808.287997
   6 | XRP                  | XRP                  |        0.7155041339106955 |   34307908872.285137 | 2474248121.70985
   7 | Cardano              | ADA                  |         0.845557365804996 |   28451406129.877007 | 1117625241.1235523
   8 | Terra                | LUNA                 |         73.41161643060934 |     27727822937.5355 | 3098404637.7947397
   9 | Solana               | SOL                  |         84.86524818533208 |   27162230598.676266 | 1917755991.5167074
  10 | Avalanche            | AVAX                 |         73.99209094139086 |    18207101060.97057 | 1587619301.2131295

# ... etc ...
```

---

I will put it on my GitHub: [python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/) in folder [API/coinmarketcap.com API](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/API/coinmarketcap.com%20API)